# How to send the message via deeplinking in MS teams?

Tags: deeplink

I have the deep link working when I click on my link, it also adds a message as s draft.

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=UserID&message=hello
```

However, I don't want the message to be added as a draft, I want the message to be sent to the predefined user(a bot), so the bot responds to the message sent.